# C++ SFML, zlib: Read single file from zip file with inputstream from sfml

Tags: c++, zip, inputstream, sfml

I would like to stream just one single file from a compressed zip file into my program. Additionally, I would like to wrap this functionality into an input stream type from SFML. But this is something I will come up with myself.
I just wanted to know, if it is possible, to read a single file directly from a zip file via an input stream?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a "code for me service". You should try to show us what you've done so far, where specifically you're stuck, etc. But besides that, I wouldn't recommend you reimplementing ZIP file handling on your own, because in the end it's not really worth the trouble. Instead, try using an existing library. [For example, there's a ready-to-use `sf::InputStream` wrapper for PhysFS](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Source:-PhysicsFS-Input-Stream), which is able to handle ZIP files and many other archive formats.

Comment: @Mario Hi. Thank you for your comment. With that in mind (that this isn't a "give me code"-service) I tried to formulate the question accordingly with "I just wanted to know, if it is possible...". I'm sorry, if my formulation wasn't correct. Sadly, my first language is german. But thank you for mentioning PhysFS :)

Comment: Everything is possible, the difference is just how much additional work it requires. :) SFML doesn't have any built-in compression (or even ZIP archive support), so you'd have to rely on third party files anyway (unless you really write everything from scratch).

Comment: That's true. But it would be a nice project to challenge oneself xD

Comment: You should read the zip specification, try to write something, and if you reach a specific problem, _then_ you ask about it. If you are not asking for code, then you are asking whether something people have done for ages is possible, which it obviously is.